# Tax Exempt Status Verfication web service

Tags: e-commerce

I'm looking for an online web service that verifies tax exempt status by tax id so that I can incorporate this business logic into the compute_total_price procedure.

What web services or methods do other e-commerce sites use to accommodate to the tax exempt organizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These guys have something that can do this.  They look to be somewhat pricey.  http://www2.guidestar.org/.  In particular, their Web Services is under custom solutions, and the price is "contact us".

Answer (score 0):

I searched a few years back and recall not having found anything useful.

I ended up adding applicable taxes where appropriate unless a flag was set in the user's profile. The latter was set by the site's owner after (manually) verifying that customers are indeed tax exempt.